# How to convert value to Stream?

Tags: dart

I am learning Dart. Here is my code:

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass() {
    stream = Stream<int>.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) => t + 1).take(3);
    myStreamController.addStream(stream);

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      myStreamController.addStream(42); // but 42 is digit, not stream!
    });

  }
}
```

Working code:

```
class MyClass {
  MyClass() {
    stream = Stream<int>.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) => t + 1).take(3);
    myStreamController.addStream(stream).then(
      (done) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            myStreamController.addStream( Stream.value(42) ); 
          });
      }
    );

  }
}
```

How I can add value to Stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Stream.value constructor:

> Creates a stream which emits a single data event before completing.
>
> This stream emits a single data event of value and then completes with
>   a done event.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.0/dart-async/Stream/Stream.value.html